# How to get metadata from IEnumerable<object> in ASP .NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, metadata, html-helper

I have custom html helper which getting IEnumerable model from view and generates html table with headers and body

please advice how can get matadata from this model

thanks

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you are trying to do correctly the below should work with minimal reflection:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MakeTable<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, IEnumerable<TValue> table)
{
    var modelMetaData = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, typeof(TValue));

    foreach (TValue row in table)
    {
        //write out table
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To get properties:

```
YourModel.GetType().GetProperties();
```

To get the name of a property:

```
property.Name;
```

To get the value of a property:

```
var result = YourModel.GetType().InvokeMember("NameOfProperty", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, YourModel, null);
```

Some more well developed examples can be found in this file on GitHub: https://github.com/jamestharpe/Rolcore/blob/master/src/Rolcore/Reflection/ObjectExtensions.cs

Comment: its gives such exception > Attempted to access a missing member . i have tried  model.GetType().InvokeMember("CreateDate", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, model, null);

Comment: The property "CreateDate" doesn't exist on your model object. Make sure you are spelling it correctly (case sensitive!) and that it's a property and not a method.